# pass out parameter to json webservice

Tags: c#, json, wcf, parameters, out

I have a Json WCF Service My methods requests out parameter how I do pass the out parameter from client

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetPerson", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Person GetPerson(out ResponseStatus ResponseStatus, int PersonID);
}
```

Comment: I fixed this problem 
try 
{$.ajax({type: "POST",url:http://localhost:55566/TestServices.svc/GetPerson",
data: { "ResponseStatus": null  ,"PersonID": "789797" },
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",success:function (data){$("#divItems").html(JSON.stringify(data));},
error: function (error) {$("#divItems").html(error.responseText);}});}
catch (e) {$("#divItems").html(e.message);}

Answer (score 0):

WCF provides an interface consumable a SOAP or REST web service and it doesn't have any physical ability to work with out parameters.